# SQL Left Join Efficiency in Presto/Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, presto

I will like to ask which will be the better option and why if I intend to LEFT JOIN a few tables? Provide an example below.

Option 1:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA a
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b
ON a.id=b.id
LEFT JOIN TABLEC c
ON a.id=c.id
LEFT JOIN TABLED d
ON a.id=d.id
```

Option 2(CTE):

```
WITH tablea_b as (
SELECT * FROM TABLEA a 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b
ON a.id=b.id)
, tablea_b_c as (
SELECT * FROM tablea_b a
LEFT JOIN TABLEC c
ON a.id=c.id)
, tablea_b_c_d as (
SELECT * FROM tablea_b_c a
LEFT JOIN TABLED d
ON a.id = d.id) SELECT * FROM tablea_b_c_d
```

Basically the differences is i left join part by part at option 2 whereas at option 1 i do it in one go. Are there any differences in terms of efficiency?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Have you compared the explain plans? The general advice is to trust the optimizer, write code easy to read and maintain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking which query will be executed faster? Don't you think just try out will be better instead of let people guess?

Comment: You should also tag with your database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) as not all databases treat CTEs the same way.

Comment: "Are there any differences in terms of efficiency?" -- It heavily depends on the specific database engine. Good databases will find out the shortcuts to run the query efficiently, while simpler databases won't optimize it. The difference is quite noticeable.